# Ruby's attr_accessor vs setter method vs local variable

Tags: ruby, attr-accessor

I have the following class defined

```
class MyClass
 attr_accessor :my_var
 def initialize
  @my_var = 0
 end

  def increment
    my_var = my_var + 1
  end
end
```

But if I run:

```
myObj = MyClass.new
puts myObj.increment # should output: 1
```

Ruby gives an error, although the expected output should be 1

ERROR MSG:

```
undefined method `+' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
```

EDIT: 
**The main question** is, what is this line doing: `my_var = my_var + 1`

Is it invoking the setter method? Or is it trying to assign a local variable? In either case, why would it give the error msg it gives?

Comment: If you only call `inc`, not `incremenet`. :)

Comment: Why would it show `1` *before* you increment?

Comment: What is the *error*? Also note that, trivially, `my_var = ..` is assigning to a *local variable* and *not* accessor; this has other repercussions as well.

Comment: You defined the method called `inc` but are trying to call the method called `increment`.

Comment: `my_var = my_var + 1` should be `self.my_var = my_var + 1`. Otherwise, as @user2864740 says, you are only assigning a local variable `my_var`.

Comment: sry, inc was typo, now fixed to increment.

Comment: Pleas see my edit on the question... so, if it is trying to assign a local variable, then why does it give no method error?

Comment: Ok, now im reading the link :p